# How to determine the length and height of a DIV relative to the amount of elements in it?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to insert several DIV elements into a main DIV - the amount of elements is dynamic and changes according to the number the user inserts.
My question is how to set the length and width of the DIV so that if I add a number of elements that should already be displayed in a wider view than the DIV then just the size of each element will decrease - but the main DIV size will not change.
I hope the question was understandable - how to insert a dynamic amount of elements (DIV) into the DIV??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Set your parent div to `display:flex` then set your children according to the ratios you need.  If you want them all the same, set them all to `flex: 1`.